# Limiting the number of auto-saves in SkyrimSE

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, pc

I've noticed with the Special Edition that they've done some work to clean things up in terms of the save system, namely with separating saves between different characters.

However, there's a slight niggle with this; I have TONS and TONS of autosaves. Ohhh by Ysmir's beard do I have a lot of autosaves. Is there a way to limit how many the game will keep before deleting/over-writing existing ones?

Comment: I believe it keeps up to 999 auto-saves... it was something I remember cleaning up when Steam Cloud would take 3-4 hours to sync, and I was wondering why it took so long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have discovered a solution!

You will need to find the location of your Skyrim.ini file. This is typically located in:

```
C:/Users/#you#/My Documents/My Games/Skyrim Special Edition
```

Open this file with a text editor of choice, and at the very bottom of the file, add the following lines:

```
[SaveGame]
iAutoSaveCount=3
```

This will limit SkyrimSE to only keep 3 autosave files, overwriting the oldest one each time. This is particularly useful because each save can be upwards of 3MB depending on content/mods, so limiting this can save a ton of space.

EDIT: Additionally, you will want to disable/clear Steam's file sync process, if you had it enabled. If you remove the bulk of your saves, Steam will try to redownload them from the cloud.